# How do I Clean up this Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

If a user ignores the form, and goes directly to the webpage, I want today's date to be the default value.

But I feel like it's bad code to copy paste all my lines of code between these two, when the only thing that is changes is the date.

How can I clean up this code?

First Results() all I do is set objdate1.DateStart myself.
In [HttpPost] I get objdate1.DateStart from the form.

```
    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        Date1 objdate1 = new Date1();
        objdate1.DateStart = DateTime.Now;

        var DataContext = new BalanceDataContext();


        DateTime earliestDate = objdate1.DateStart.Value.AddMonths(-13);

        //Tons of Code omitted Here ---------------------------


        ViewBag.Metric = 1;
        ViewBag.Message = objdate1.DateStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
        ViewBag.Title2 = "% of Electric Estimated";
        ViewBag.Descript = "Percentage of estimated electric bills per Month.";
        return View(new QueryView { Date2 = totalbills, Date1 = totalEstimated });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Results(Date1 objdate1)
    {
        var DataContext = new BalanceDataContext();


        DateTime earliestDate = objdate1.DateStart.Value.AddMonths(-13);

        //Exact same Code omitted Here ---------------------------


        ViewBag.Metric = 1;
        ViewBag.Message = objdate1.DateStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
        ViewBag.Title2 = "% of Electric Estimated";
        ViewBag.Descript = "Percentage of estimated electric bills per Month.";
        return View(new QueryView { Date2 = totalbills, Date1 = totalEstimated });
    }
```

Comment: Write a third function that takes `objdate1` and returns an ActionResult?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? because I'm not sure why the corresponding get and post actions should share so much code.  you should also introduce view models that mirror that data on the screen.  I'm not sure why you'd put 2 fields in a view model and then have 4 others in the ViewBag?  why not keep them all in the view model?

Comment: @Fran I just prefer Viewbag for sending simple strings to a view, because it looks neater and easier to find for me. Personal preference. Also, see below for the result. I put all the code within a separate class, and I just call it when I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User RandomStrangler from the C# Freenode gave me the answer:

"Have logic in a separate class, and just call that from both actions."

So I created a separate class called Query's, and do this:

```
    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        Date1 objdate1 = new Date1();
        objdate1.DateStart = DateTime.Now;

        Querys estview = new Querys();

        ViewBag.Metric = 1;
        ViewBag.Message = objdate1.DateStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
        ViewBag.Title2 = "% of Electric Estimated";
        ViewBag.Descript = "Percentage of estimated electric bills per Month.";
        return View(estview.estimatedbills(objdate1.DateStart));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Results(Date1 objdate1)
    {
        Querys estview = new Querys();

        ViewBag.Metric = 1;
        ViewBag.Message = objdate1.DateStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
        ViewBag.Title2 = "% of Electric Estimated";
        ViewBag.Descript = "Percentage of estimated electric bills per Month.";

        return View(estview.estimatedbills(objdate1.DateStart));
    }
```

A lot neater.

Answer (score 1):

Make your parameter nullable and remove the parameterless method.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Results(Date1? objdate1)
{
var DataContext = new BalanceDataContext();

if (!objdate1.HasValue){
    objdate1 = new Date1();
    objdate1.DateStart = DateTime.Now;
}

DateTime earliestDate = objdate1.DateStart.Value.AddMonths(-13);

//Exact same Code omitted Here ---------------------------


ViewBag.Metric = 1;
ViewBag.Message = objdate1.DateStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
ViewBag.Title2 = "% of Electric Estimated";
ViewBag.Descript = "Percentage of estimated electric bills per Month.";
return View(new QueryView { Date2 = totalbills, Date1 = totalEstimated });
```

}

Comment: If I remove the parameterless method, I will just get "The resource cannot be found" error when going to the webpage.

Comment: because its its labeled as "httppost". It doenst need to be